# Oauth2 hidden field with token

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I have a laravel web app with oauth2, I get the password grant token and it works perfect.

But the problem is this:

When I get the token I can start to use the API, I have a form to store food brands... I have to use the API to store.. I have small form with brand_name and brand_description but my problem is:

do I have to send the token that I got before? and if it's yes, should I send the token in a hidden field but the name of that field, it is access_token? or just token?

Thanks

Comment: Use an OAuth 2.0 library and have it prepare the correct request for you. Go via your application backend

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Passport package from Laravel? If so you don't pass your token in your form, but instead you send your token in your header.

> When calling routes that are protected by Passport, your application's API consumers should specify their access token as a Bearer token in the Authorization header of their request. For example, when using the Guzzle HTTP library:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
    ],
]);
```

For further information check out the Laravel document here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#creating-a-password-grant-client

Comment: How can I pass the token in my form? what field should i put? Thanks

Comment: @JesúsCova You pass your token in your Http request header, under the Authorization header. What frontend framework do you use? or you are making this API for APP? Which type of frontend application are you making?

Comment: I am using to create the backend and API with laravel and an Android App and IOS App consume the API.

Comment: @JesúsCova Like I said in the previouse comment, you don't pass your token in your form data, you put your token in your http request/ ajax request header. This same goes to your ISO/Android App.